# error while using git clone

Tags: ssh, git, clone

I'm trying to use `git clone` to clone a forked project for compiling.
The input/output are as follows:

```
 preet@Preet-HP-620:~/clones$ git clone git@github.com:Preet23/android_vendor_resurrection.git
 Cloning into 'android_vendor_resurrection'...
 Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[MY IP]' to the list of known hosts.
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

This output is as it is except '[MY IP]' it's replaced with the actual IP.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to put use public key u can always use http protocol to access github (which might not be the best thing to do, but can be quick solution).

PS: I am putting this as answer as i dont have much reputation to add comment.